# Get the Mojave dynamic wallpaper back after upgrading to Big Sur

Tags: macos, mojave, big-sur, wallpaper

I just upgraded to macOS Big Sur and I noticed the dynamic wallpaper from Mojave is missing, although the one from Catalina is still there. Does anybody know how to the the Mojave dynamic wallpaper back in Big Sur? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This one?
[image]
[image]

Just download the file and then right click and "Set Desktop Picture":
https://files.rb.gd/mojave_dynamic.heic

---

Or have a look [here](https://dynamicwallpaper.club/gallery?section=search&q=mojave) for more.

Answer (score 2):

You could try downloading this: https://dynamicwallpaper.club/wallpaper/r1olj9zggjl

And apply it using this tutorial: https://dynamicwallpaper.club/docs